# Is there a strategy for multiple user and parallel computing

Tags: parallel-processing, celery, joblib, multiple-users

-Hi, all,

We have created a website on google cloud that needs time consuming calculation. We want to use parallel computing to speed up the calculation. At the same time, we want other users can query the results in the database. However, if we adopted the parallel computing, when one user is calculating online, other users must wait in queue until he/she finished the job even he/she just want to query some result from the database.

If we allowed multi users can access the website at the same time (no one need to wait in queue), we cannot use the parallel computing at the same time.

It only takes a few seconds to query the result from the database, but it will take a few minutes to finish the calculation online.

Specifically, I’m currently using a library called Celery to handle the parallel computations for multiple API calls, and joblib to handle the parallel computations for the CHO calculations. But they don’t really work well together.

Would you please tell me what framework/software can be used to solve my problem?

Thanks

Erick

Comment: What is the actual question? I don't understand the problem... You cannot use more resources than available. The problem should already be present without the parallel computation if the number of user is bigger than the number of core. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Thank you. I ran parallel computation with GPU, and ran codes with multiple users with CPUs. But if I set the codes with the modes of multiple users, the codes can only use CPU resources, no GPU can be used.

Comment: What "mode" are you talking about? GPU have no issue with running multi-user codes as well as CPUs. Resources are shared based on the (OS) scheduler used and its parameters. In general, multiple users can run codes using the CPU + GPU resources simultaneously (not the same logical cores at the same time though). Thus from the hardware/OS PoV, I still do not see any issue. It looks like you are limited by a framework/software (which is not specified in the question).

Comment: I’m currently using a library called Celery to handle the parallel computations for multiple API calls, and joblib to handle the parallel computations for the CHO calculations. But they don’t really work well together.

Comment: Hi, Jérôme Richard, would you please tell me what framework/software can be used to solve my problem?

Comment: I am not sure I can help here : I do not know Celery nor know what are CHO calculations (and do not really understand the precise problem). Basides, please note that recommandation of tools and framework are off-topic on Stack-Overflow. It might be useful to add more precise tags (for notify people who track them) like the one for Celery. Adding more precision is certainly critical for them to better understand the actual problem, possibly with some piece of code for things to be more practical. Maybe it also worth opening a new question with all these changes taken into account.

Comment: Thank you. I revised my question according to your suggestions.